# Azure AD - Multi-Tenant with Daemon Service Authentication flow, what limits tenants from accessing other tenants users?

Tags: azure, daemon, multi-tenant, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a Service/Dameon application to handle the authentication process for `Microsoft Graph SDK`. I pretty much created a `HttpWebRequest` and created a URL which I passed in my application's `secret` and `client_id` which generated an `access_token`. This `access_token` was then used with the Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK to authenticate for OneDrive for Business.

I have successfully proofed this out for a single tenant and it is able to pull back all the user's OneDrive metadata on files and folder facets. My question is if I wanted to allow access for other tenants to this application, what users would they see?

If **Tenant A** creates an application that reads all the non-global admin accounts to pull back OneDrive for Business meta-data and **Tenant B** has its own list of non-global admin accounts where **Tenant B** wishes to read from - Where is the restrictions to limit **Tenant B** to only having access to their own list of non-global users.

The only thing I can think of is that **Tenant B** would need to create their own `client_id` and `secret`- is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I can think of is that Tenant B would need to create their own client_id and secret- is there another way of doing this?

Before the application could interact with Azure AD through OAuth 2.0 protocol, we need to create the corresponding **service principal** to the target tenant. When we register the application on the Azure portal, the portal already create the **service principal** for us in the developer's tenant.

And if we are developing an multi-tenant app, the users on the other tenant need to grant the permission. After users consent, a service principal is created in users' tenant.

So another way is, we need to provide a way to enable users in other tenant to able to consent. For example, we can use the **authorization code grant** flow. Here is an example for your reference( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)):

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&state=12345
```

And after the service principal is created on users' tenant, we need to use the users's tenant to acquire the token like below

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{users' tenantId}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<clientId>
&client_secret=<clientSecret>
&resource=<resource>
```

Here are some helpful documents for your reference:

[Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects)

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#related-content)

Comment: It should be an admin who consents the app for first time so the principal is created. And it should be noted that if the app uses only delegated permissions then users really only can access their tenant's data.

Comment: @Fei Xue - MSFT, thank you for answering. Maybe you can clear up some confusion for me. I have created a URL to generate an `authorization_code` and logged in as an admin and granted permissions. Should I expect to see the application that was granted permissions to under the applications section? I do not show anything there?

Comment: Yes, it should show both the delegate permission and application permission when users grant the permission. To ensure that the app was not consent before in that tenant, we can enforce the showing consent by appending the parameter `prompt=consent` when sending the request.